# How to save the shuffled order of an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, radio-button

What I want to do:

1. Shuffle six photos that are displayed in a single row. Each photo has a radio button below. This is a single-choice question. Participants choose one of the photos as their answers.
2. Record the order of the radio buttons or photos each time they are shuffled, so that I know which photo did a participant choose. **I also need to know the position of the photo they choose in the array, so I need to know the order of the array that is shuffled. For example, if a participant chooses "picture 5," I need to know a) he has chosen "picture5" and b) the position of "picture 5" in the array, e.g. position 1 in the array.**  This is why having only values of the radio buttons don't work. Sorry for not making this clear.

What I think I should do:

1. Create an array for the photos or radio buttons.
2. Use a function to shuffle the pictures.
3. **Create a function or something to get the order of the array each time it is shuffled.**
4. Use `document.write('<input type="hidden" name="PhotoArray" value="' + lineup1.toString() + '">');` to record the order of the array each time it is shuffled. I'm putting the code on Amazon Turk, so what the code does is print out the order of the array into the excel file.

I've been searching online and experimenting with different codes for step 3, but nothing works so far. Does anyone know what a good solution would be? Thanks so much.

I tried to create an array, then assign the array to the radio buttons, then record the order of the array. It didn't work, because the array wasn't successfully assigned to the radio buttons.

```
var RadioArray = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

Shuffle(RadioArray);

function RadioOrder(){
    $("#version1page11").hide(); // This hides the previous page.
    $("#version1page12").show(); // This shows the page on which the photos are displayed.
    $("#lp" + RadioArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*RadioArray.length)]).show();
   }

document.write(RadioArray)
```

I also tried to create an array using IDs. Didn't work. Any suggested solution would be helpful!

My original code:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


//This function shuffles the photos.
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var a = $("#lole > div").remove().toArray();
        for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var bi = a[i];
        var bj = a[j];
        a[i] = bj;
        a[j] = bi;
    }
    $("#lole").append(a);
});
```

This is the div for all the photos and radio buttons:

```
<div id="lole" class="checkboxgroup" align="center">

    <label id="le1" for="lp1"><img src="picture1.jpg" height="150" width="120" id="ak1"/><br />

        <input type="radio" name="Choice" id="lp1" value="picture1" />

    </label>

    <label id="le2" for="lp2"><img src="picture.jpg" height="150" width="120" id="ak2"/><br />

        <input type="radio" name="Choice" id="lp2" value="picture2" />

    </label>

    <label id="le3" for="lp3"><img src="picture2.jpg" height="150" width="120" id="ak3"/><br />

        <input type="radio" name="Choice" id="lp3" value="picture3" />

    </label>

    <label id="le4" for="lp4"><img src="picture4.jpg" height="100" width="120" id="ak4" /><br />

        <input type="radio" name="Choice" id="lp4" value="picture4" />

    </label>

    <label id="le5" for="lp5"><img src="picture5.jpg" height="150" width="120" id="ak5"/><br />

        <input type="radio" name="Choice" id="lp5" value="picture5" />

    </label>

    <label id="le6" for="lp6"><img src="picture6.jpg" height="200" width="120" id="ak6"/><br />

        <input type="radio" name="Choice" id="lp6" value="picture6" />

    </label>

</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't load two versions of jQuery at the same time.

Comment: The value of the radio button tells you which one they chose, it gets shuffled together with the image.

Comment: "Record the order of the radio buttons or photos each time they are shuffled, so that I know which photo did a participant choose." -- As @Barmar mentioned, the value of the radio button will tell you which photo did a participant choose regardless of how the images are shuffled.

Comment: @AndrewL: Note also: "to record the order of the array each time it is shuffled."  I'm guessing this is an attempt to do some analysis on whether users are more likely to choose a given photo (or any photo) in a particular position.  So the order of the photos is also included in the request.

Comment: @AndrewL: I also need to know the position of the photo they choose in the array, so I need to know the order of the array that is shuffled. For example, if a participant chooses "picture 5," I need to know a) he has chosen "picture5" and b) the position of "picture 5" in the array, e.g. position 1 in the array. This is why having only values of the radio buttons don't work. Sorry for not making this clear.

Comment: Is it really `$("#lole > div")`?  The sample markup makes me think `$("#lole > label")`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: Exactly. Thanks for making this clear!

Comment: To those voting to close this question for "too broad": I don't think so.  There is clear effort here, and the only thing missing could be phrased, "How do I save the shuffled order in order to submit it with my request?"  That's not overbroad.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: This function calls all the elements in the div id "lole," shuffle the elements, then put them back into the div lole. I think #lole > label would only call elements in a single <label></label>?

Comment: @Barmar:  I also need to know the position of the photo they choose in the array, so I need to know the order of the array that is shuffled. For example, if a participant chooses "picture 5," I need to know a) he has chosen "picture5" and b) the position of "picture 5" in the array, e.g. position 1 in the array. This is why having only values of the radio buttons don't work. Sorry for not making this clear.

Comment: Why not put the index into a data attribute of the radio button?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  If you haven't done so, please **[take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and visit the **[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)**.

---

I think the key would be something like:

```
var order = a.map(function(label) {return label.htmlFor;})
```

which records the order of the ids.  In this snippet, I just `console.log` the results, but you can add it to your form using jQuery methods (not `document.write` -- it's a little late for that!)

Note also that I use `$("#lole > label")` rather then your `$("#lole > div")`.  `"#lole > label"` represents the collection of `label` elements which are direct children of the element with id `lole`.  These are what we shuffle.  I also changed the images sizes to get them to fit, and added numbering so you can see how the shuffle happened.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = $("#lole > label").remove().toArray();
  for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var bi = a[i];
    var bj = a[j];
    a[i] = bj;
    a[j] = bi;
  }
  $("#lole").append(a);
  $("#choose").click(function(e) {
    var order = a.map(function(label) {return label.htmlFor;})
    console.log("Chosen: " + $(":radio[name=Choice]:checked").closest("label").prop("for"));
    console.log("Order: " + order);
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="lole" class="checkboxgroup" align="center">
  <label id="le1" for="lp1"><img src="picture1.jpg" height="50" width="50" id="ak1"/><br/>
    1: <input type="radio" name="Choice" id="lp1" value="picture1" />
  </label>

  <label id="le2" for="lp2"><img src="picture.jpg" height="50" width="50" id="ak2"/><br />
    2: <input type="radio" name="Choice" id="lp2" value="picture2" />
  </label>

  <label id="le3" for="lp3"><img src="picture2.jpg" height="50" width="50" id="ak3"/><br/>
    3: <input type="radio" name="Choice" id="lp3" value="picture3" />
  </label>

  <label id="le4" for="lp4"><img src="picture4.jpg" height="50" width="50" id="ak4"/><br/>
    4: <input type="radio" name="Choice" id="lp4" value="picture4" />
  </label>

  <label id="le5" for="lp5"><img src="picture5.jpg" height="50" width="50" id="ak5"/><br/>
    5: <input type="radio" name="Choice" id="lp5" value="picture5" />
  </label>

  <label id="le6" for="lp6"><img src="picture6.jpg" height="50" width="50" id="ak6"/><br/>
    6: <input type="radio" name="Choice" id="lp6" value="picture6" />
  </label>
</div>

<button id="choose" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!! Can I ask, why 'document.write' is "too late" to work? Is it because the array is local not global? I've been using document.write('input' ...) for exporting the order of arrays from mTurk because 'console.log' cannot export the order of arrays when participants answer on mTurk.

Comment: [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) only works on the document stream as it's being loaded.  It cannot modify a loaded document, only replace it.  But just as you can shuffle elements with DOM methods (through jQuery in your case), you can also add them.  So you can add a hidden field to your form to hold the sort order when you shuffle or when you go to submit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your generous help!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of the selected radio button using jQuery:

```
var index = $(":radio[name=Choice]:checked").closest("label").index();
```